# Issue with Azure Storage CDN And CORS

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cdn

Having an issue with Azure storage CDN.  We have it configured for CORS, basically we allow all headers and origins (*), and GET|HEAD|
OPTIONS.  Everything works fine when we are using the storage direct host.   When we switch it over to use the CDN host,the OPTIONS request stops returning any of the allow headers and causes cross origin failures.  On other gets I do get the allow origin header but nothing else.  Anyone seen this or am I overlooking a config option somewhere?   Happens locally talking to Azure and on our Azure hosted site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure CDN profiles from Akamai currently do not tunnel OPTIONS requests. There is a patch currently underway to enable OPTIONS requests for cors pre-flight.

If you don't use pre-flight requests, does CORS work?

Comment: It does seem non-pre flight is working.   This is good information, thanks!